# jQuery attr and prop combination in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a part of my script using jQuery.

```
        jQuery(".disabableInputField").addClass("disabledInputField");
        cstaIpVal[0] = jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet").val();
        cstaIpVal[1] = jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet\\.netmask").val();
        jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet\\.netmask").val("");
        jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet").val("");
        jQuery(".disabableInputField").attr("disabled",true);           
        jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet\\.netmask").prop("path", "");
        jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet").prop("path","");
```

The question is, why the combination of calling prop and attr doesn't work. If I call `attr("disabled",true)` then the property set `prop("path","")` does not work. When I switch the order, then attribute set does not work. I can not achieve setting disabled attribute via prop. How can I combine attr and prop calling? Or how can I set disabled attribute of html element via prop calling?

Thank you.

Comment: You're misusing both methods. `prop` is for `disabled`, `attr` is for custom attributes (`path`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's becouse of missuse of methods. Use "prop" for setting properties, and "attr" for setting attributes. Not vice verse. The following worked fine for me.

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#test").prop("disabled",true);
    jQuery("#test").attr("path", "");
</script>
<!-- result -->
<input disabled="" id="test" type="text" path="">
```

Comment: code after change:
`jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet\\.netmask").prop("disabled",true); jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet").prop("disabled",true);        
            jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet\\.netmask").attr("path", "");
            jQuery("#private-circuit-to-csta-subnet").attr("path","");`
path is correct, it is empty, but disabled attribute still does not work, it's still an editable field :/ I'm really confused now

Comment: Please show your html markup for #private-circuit-to-csta-subnet

Comment: `<html:input class="disabableInputField" id="${property.key}" path="cstaProperties[${propsLoop.index}].value" />`

it can't be changed, I need to use this version
Thank you for help.

Comment: You are using rendering engine, it can create some other element instead of "input". Please show what happens after render (View page source in browser)

Comment: this is first render of the html
`<input id="private-circuit-to-csta-subnet" class="disabableInputField" name="cstaProperties[0].value" value="10.4.0.0" type="text">`
after disabling the input field and clearing the value
`<input path="" disabled="" id="private-circuit-to-csta-subnet" class="disabableInputField" name="cstaProperties[0].value" value="10.4.0.0" type="text">`
and after enabling input and putting back the value
`<input path="10.4.0.0" id="private-circuit-to-csta-subnet" class="disabableInputField" name="cstaProperties[0].value" value="10.4.0.0" type="text">`

Comment: Now I see the point of failure wont be the path attribute, but the value attribute, but in html I posted before, I am setting path not value...

Comment: To set the value for input use $('#id').val('your value'). And if you still having issues with disabling/enabling inputs you'd better check for some extra js-libs that are loaded at the page, because this class="disabableInputField" really confuses me/

Answer (score 2):

You can disable element with :

```
jQuery(".disabableInputField").prop("disabled", true);
```

See : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/

And maybe this : [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)